# Add up numbers from file

Tags: java, file, java.util.scanner

I have a text file `numbers.txt` with some lines with numbers, separated by a comma (`\n` is not visible, of course):

```
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, \n
6, 7, 8, 9, 10, \n
11, 12, 13, 14, 15
```

I want to read and add up them, so that the overall result would be 120.
This is my code:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class App1 {

    int res;

    public App1() {
     Scanner sc = null;
        try {
            sc = new Scanner(new File("numbers.txt")).useDelimiter(",");
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            System.err.println(ex);
        }
      while (sc.hasNextInt()) {
        res += sc.nextInt();
      }
        System.out.println("Result: " + res);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        App1 app = new App1();
    }
}
```

Unfortunately I only get the first number:

```
Result: 1
```

Comment: Maybe the delimiter must include the whitespace: `", "`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with `useDelimiter("[,\\s]+")`. Currently you are replacing standard delimiter `\p{javaWhitespace}+` with only `,` which means that after finding first integer scanner will be

```
1,| 2, 3, 4, 5, \n
  ^here
```

so next characters will be `[space][digit]`. Since space is not delimiter anymore and is definitely not digit this data can't be accepted in `hasNextInt()` test.

Answer (score 2):

Try `.useDelimiter("[,\\s]+");`.  If you're only using delimiter(","), the next char is whitespace, and you can't use `hasNextInt()` on white space.

Comment: `\s` allready includes `\n`: See http://www.vogella.com/articles/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html#regex_metacharacters